# Extending the Users section of the admin panel

Tags: plugin-development, users

Is it possible to add additional tab views that aren't related to user fields?

We would like to show a summary of user account activity that includes details of purchases they have made. A plugin would work obviously but we would want all of this information in the existing user area rather than in a new area for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're best bet is going to be with a plugin that has its own, separate section for displaying the purchase information.

Comment: So I assume there are no other options right now beyond of course hacking the core. Anything on the roadmap?

Comment: Yeah and the problem with hacking the core is an auto-update could overwrite any files you've changed at any time. Will have to think about how we can let a plugin hook into that logic.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to write a separate plugin/template to display custom user data in the control panel - it's not possible to extend the Users page.